# How can I use LUIS in app.js to recognize dialogs that I have in different folders

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Microsoft BotbuilderSDK: 3.15.0
Language: NodeJs

I have my dialogs in different folders. However, I am trying to initialize them in the app.js folder so that I can use LUIS when the intent matches the dialog, but it is not working.

NOTE - Each dialog works when I call them in a structure similar to the following:

```
session.beginDialog('hello:Hello')
```

Here is the full source code:

```html
require('dotenv').config();
const restify = require('restify');

const builder = require('botbuilder');

var fs = require('fs');

var clients = require('restify-clients');

var azure = require('botbuilder-azure');

var listenPort = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978;

var server = restify.createServer()

server.listen(listenPort, '::', () => {
  console.log(`smooth like a baby's bottom`)
});


var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});


var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.endDialog(`I'm sorry, I did not understand '${session.message.text}'.\nType 'help' to know more about me :)`)
}).set('storage', cosmosStorage);


var luisRL = new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL).onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
  var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0
  callback(null, enabled)
});


var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [luisRL] });
bot.recognizer(intents);


server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
  if (message.membersAdded) {

    greetings = 'welcome to Joey's Pizza?'

    message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
      if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
        bot.send(new builder.Message()
          .address(message.address)
          .text(greetings)
        )
      }
    })
  }
});

bot.library(require('./dialogs/reservations').createLibrary());
bot.library(require('./dialogs/order').createLibrary());
bot.library(require('./dialogs/cancellations').createLibrary());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example, demonstrating a dialog in a library file triggering from a LUIS intent:

With a startup file such as:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const restify = require('restify');
const builder = require('botbuilder');

var listenPort = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978;
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(listenPort, '::', () => {
  console.log(`smooth like a baby's bottom`)
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage(); 

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.endDialog(`I'm sorry, I did not understand '${session.message.text}'.\nType 'help' to know more about me :)`)
}).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);

var luisRL = new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL).onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
  var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0
  callback(null, enabled)
});

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [luisRL] });
bot.recognizer(intents);

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
  if (message.membersAdded) {

    greetings = `Ask to set or change your name...`;

    message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
      if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
        bot.send(new builder.Message()
          .address(message.address)
          .text(greetings)
        )
      }
    })
  }
});

bot.library(require('./dialogs/profile').createLibrary());
```

Having the following /dialogs/profile/index.js

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');


var lib = new builder.Library('profile');
exports.createLibrary = function () {
    return lib.clone();
}

lib.dialog('changeName', [
    function (session) {
        debugger;
        session.dialogData.updating = session.userData.hasOwnProperty('name');
        var prompt =  session.dialogData.updating ? "What would you like to change your name to?" : "Hi... What's your name?";
        builder.Prompts.text(session, prompt);
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.endDialog("Got it %s...", session.userData.name);
    }    
]).triggerAction({ matches: 'ChangeNameIntent' });
```

With the following LUIS Model:

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "3.1.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "ChangeNameLuisModel",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "ChangeNameIntent"
    },
    {
      "name": "getage"
    },
    {
      "name": "None"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "speed",
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [],
  "patternAnyEntities": [],
  "regex_entities": [],
  "prebuiltEntities": [
    {
      "name": "number",
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "model_features": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "patterns": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "allow me to change my name",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "change my name",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "change name",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "i am 10 years old",
      "intent": "getage",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "i am 12 years old",
      "intent": "getage",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "i want to change my name",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "let me alter my name",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "name change",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "please change my name",
      "intent": "ChangeNameIntent",
      "entities": []
    }
  ],
  "settings": []
}
```

Comment: I tried the approach but I keep getting 

UniversalBot("*") routing "change my name" from "emulator"
Session.beginDialog(/)
/ - waterfall() step 1 of 1
/ - Session.sendBatch() sending 0 message(s)

Comment: I'm sorry, can you re-word that.  I do not understand.